# Tags with icons are shifted to the top

Tags: bug, tags, design

I noticed that question tags with icons are shifted to the top. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337350/meteor-accounts-google-error-10-on-android-simulator):

> [image]

Excuse me for my free-hand red ... lines.

I think all tags should be aligned in single line.

Reproduced in Chrome/Firefox for iOS 11.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. I'm on Chrome 62.0.3202.94 x64 (up to date until now).

Comment: @FirstOne looks like this happens only for iOS. My screenshot is from Chrome on iPad on iOS11.

Comment: Where ever did I put that imgur link...

Comment: @Will I did not recognize you in the makeup at first... :)